# LocalNotification on iOS8 not working properly when app not running

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uilocalnotification

I have an app that uses local notification. Until recently everything worked fine, but after iOS 8 was released, my local notifications aren't working when app is not running(removed from processes). This is my code in app delegate where I set my local notifications.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{      
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:localReceived object:self userInfo:notification.userInfo];

    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{     
    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
        UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }
    else if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:)])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }

    ...

    // Local notificaiton example. Icon badge
    UILocalNotification *locationNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    NSLog(@"locationNotification:%@",locationNotification.alertBody);
    if (locationNotification) {
        // Set icon badge number to zero
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        // call local notification method
        [self application:[UIApplication sharedApplication] didReceiveLocalNotification:locationNotification];

    }

    return YES;

}
```

When my app is not running, the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method is called. In it I call the **didReceiveLocalNotification** method again where I call **postNotificationName**. I put the observer in my ViewControllers ViewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(recieveLocalNotification:) name:localReceived object:nil];
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the method **recieveLocalNotification:** is never called when app is not running. It's called every time when app is in background or running. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your application is not running and is relaunched into the background then your viewController will not be instantiated, so it cannot receive the notification.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, thanks for the quick reply! The VC I'm using is instantiated in the **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method(where the 3 dots are in my code snippet). Could it be that that is still too fast? What can I do to circumvent taht? Add a NSTimer?

Comment: Why not invoke the method directly rather than relying on decoupling via NSNotificationcentre?

Comment: Well, the truth is I'm fairly new to iOS development and I'm not sure how that is done exactly. Could I bother you to write me a few lines of code in a comment?

Comment: Once you have loaded the viewController, assuming it is in a variable `myVC` you would just say `[myVC theMethodToCall]`

Comment: I'm not using storyboards. I tried something like this already but it doesn't seem to work for me. But thanks for the code anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69001/discussion-between-paulw11-and-iphonenoob).

Answer (score 0):

`-viewDidLoad` is called after the view of view controller is instantiated, the view is instantiated after the `viewController.view` is accessed for the first time.

So you can try call your `viewController.view` before posting the notification.